# React + Django app refreshes for every deletion in Django admin panel

Tags: django, reactjs, redux

I'm not really sure what to share (i.e. which part of my application code) as I'm still a beginner with React so please bear with me.

I have a React application running on top of a Django application. Basically, there are Django Admin Panel URLS, REST API URLS in Django, and **one** path to catch all paths that don't belong to the first two groups.

I have a page (or a React Container) that calls Django's REST API to query all entries in the `users` DB Table. This part is okay but what I've noticed is, everytime I manually delete a row in the Django Admin Panel, the whole page refreshes. What are possible reasons for this?

By the way, I'm using Redux as well to manage the whole application state.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your code, but I would guess that your delete button is part of a form. When you click this the default behaviour of the form is to reload the page. You can invoke `preventDefault` on the event to stop the browser from reloading.

Comment: @Tholle yeah I don't really know which part of my code should I include in my question :/ Anyway, but the form is in the Django Admin panel, and not in the React page (or Container)?

Comment: Too generic to find an answer here. How is running the react app? Inside a django template? Are you just importing react and redux libs in the head of the document or have you created a create-react-app project?  By admin panel you mean the django admin app, right?

Comment: @abidibo 

"How is running the react app? Inside a django template? Are you just importing react and redux libs in the head of the document or have you created a create-react-app project?" - Yes, the whole React app is inside a single Django template.

"By admin panel you mean the django admin app, right?" - Yes sir, that is right